# Unable to push data to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Beginner to `Firebase` , just installed, trying to push data, did as per their docs, but still can't see anything in the web console.
Here is the code :

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_big_board);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

    Firebase myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://futurister.firebaseio.com/");

    FeedMessage msg = new FeedMessage("Tom", "High five, if it works!");

    myFirebaseRef.push().setValue(msg);



}
```

code of FeedMessage class:

```
  public class FeedMessage
{
    String message;
    String name;

    public FeedMessage() {
    }

    public FeedMessage(String name, String message) {
        this.message = message;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? , Kindly, let me know. Thanks

Comment: I just pushed a few values to your database from a Chrome console and I can add new child nodes fine. What are you checking in the web console?

Comment: Yeah, I can see that, but I cant see any of mine ,

Comment: Check the internet connection on your device/emulator. I pasted your code into a test app and It was just failing from Android for me too. But after restarting the emulator it started working. I'm pretty sure I had this same problem at a demo recently. :-)

Comment: I am testing on Device, Nexus5 , The other Google places API works fine, if it was the issue of internet Connectivity.. . Is there anything wrong in the code? Anything  to add to manifest?

Comment: Yes, retried, works fine :)

Comment: Did you add INTERNET permission to your Manifest.xml? See step 3 here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/quickstart.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, In this case! **Keep Calm** . Try building again and run . did work for me

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the permissions in Database>Rules?
By Default they are set to null 
change it to this and try to see if it recieves the data

```
{
  "rules": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
    }
}
```